# Why does fastlane add_badge work for me locally but fail on App Center

Tags: fastlane, visual-studio-app-center

As per the title, if I execute the following (for example) from my local machine, the command succeeds and all my icons get updated correctly:

`fastlane addBadge branch_name:staging build_number:1558591886 branch_color:green`

However, when the build runs on Visual Studio App Center, it errors with the following output:

```
[32mDriving the lane 'addBadge' [0m
[06:46:53]: [32m-----------------------[0m
[06:46:53]: [32m--- Step: add_badge ---[0m
[06:46:53]: [32m-----------------------[0m
[06:46:53]: [32mStart adding badges...[0m
[06:46:54]: './iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/icon120x120.png'
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFont
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.1/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.1/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.0.dylib
+---------------+----------+
|       [33mLane Context[0m       |
+---------------+----------+
| PLATFORM_NAME |          |
| LANE_NAME     | addBadge |
+---------------+----------+
[06:46:54]: [31mNo such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - 1558593854-staging-green.svg.png[0m
```

For App Center, I'm calling the `fastlane addBadge` command from `appcenter-pre-build.sh`.

**Question:** Why is this error happening, what do I do to fix it?

**Update 1:** After adding `--verbose` to the `addBadge` command:

Here's what I get locally:

```
Driving the lane 'addBadge' 
INFO [2019-05-24 09:58:54.78]: -----------------------
INFO [2019-05-24 09:58:54.78]: --- Step: add_badge ---
INFO [2019-05-24 09:58:54.78]: -----------------------
INFO [2019-05-24 09:58:54.86]: gem 'badge' is already installed
WARN [2019-05-24 09:58:54.87]: Install RSVG to get better results for shields on top of your icon
WARN [2019-05-24 09:58:54.87]: 
WARN [2019-05-24 09:58:54.87]: Install it using (RSVG):
INFO [2019-05-24 09:58:54.87]: $ brew install librsvg
WARN [2019-05-24 09:58:54.87]: 
DEBUG [2019-05-24 09:58:54.88]: Verbose active... VERSION: 0.10.0
DEBUG [2019-05-24 09:58:54.88]: Parameters: {:shield=>"1558591886-staging-green", :no_badge=>true, :glob=>"{/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/*.{png,PNG},/Droid/Resources/**/{icon}.{png,PNG}}", :dark=>nil, :alpha=>nil, :alpha_channel=>nil, :custom=>nil, :badge_gravity=>nil, :shield_parameters=>nil, :shield_io_timeout=>nil, :shield_geometry=>nil, :shield_gravity=>nil, :shield_scale=>nil, :shield_no_resize=>nil, :grayscale=>false}
INFO [2019-05-24 09:58:54.88]: Start adding badges...
DEBUG [2019-05-24 09:58:54.88]: Trying to load image from shields.io. Timeout: 10s
DEBUG [2019-05-24 09:58:54.88]: URL: https://img.shields.io/badge/1558591886-staging-green.png
INFO [2019-05-24 09:58:56.36]: './iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/icon120x120.png'
DEBUG [2019-05-24 09:58:56.36]: Adding shields.io image ontop of icon
INFO [2019-05-24 09:58:56.43]: './iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/icon58x58.png'
```

And here's what's outputted on App Center:

```
INFO [2019-05-24 00:13:28.42]: [32mDriving the lane 'addBadge' [0m
INFO [2019-05-24 00:13:28.43]: [32m-----------------------[0m
INFO [2019-05-24 00:13:28.43]: [32m--- Step: add_badge ---[0m
INFO [2019-05-24 00:13:28.43]: [32m-----------------------[0m
INFO [2019-05-24 00:13:28.50]: [32mgem 'badge' is already installed[0m
DEBUG [2019-05-24 00:13:28.51]: [34mVerbose active... VERSION: 0.10.0[0m
DEBUG [2019-05-24 00:13:28.51]: [34mParameters: {:shield=>"1558656638-staging-green", :no_badge=>true, :glob=>"{/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/*.{png,PNG},/Droid/Resources/**/{icon}.{png,PNG}}", :dark=>nil, :alpha=>nil, :alpha_channel=>nil, :custom=>nil, :badge_gravity=>nil, :shield_parameters=>nil, :shield_io_timeout=>nil, :shield_geometry=>nil, :shield_gravity=>nil, :shield_scale=>nil, :shield_no_resize=>nil, :grayscale=>false}[0m
INFO [2019-05-24 00:13:28.51]: [32mStart adding badges...[0m
DEBUG [2019-05-24 00:13:28.51]: [34mTrying to load image from shields.io. Timeout: 10s[0m
DEBUG [2019-05-24 00:13:28.51]: [34mURL: https://img.shields.io/badge/1558656638-staging-green.svg[0m
INFO [2019-05-24 00:13:29.27]: './iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset/icon120x120.png'
DEBUG [2019-05-24 00:13:29.27]: [34mAdding shields.io image ontop of icon[0m
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFont
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.0.dylib
WARN [2019-05-24 00:13:29.34]: [33m[33mLane Context:[0m
INFO [2019-05-24 00:13:29.34]: {:PLATFORM_NAME=>nil, :LANE_NAME=>"addBadge"}
ERROR [2019-05-24 00:13:29.34]: [31mNo such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - 1558656638-staging-green.svg.png[0m
```

It seems like on the build agent, an svg is being requested instead of a png. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: `add_badge` comes from https://github.com/HazAT/fastlane-plugin-badge I assume? What output are you getting when you run the lane with `--verbose`? (both locally and on App Cneter)

Comment: @janpio Thanks for the suggestion. Please see Update 1.

Comment: If it uses .svg or .png is decided by the presence of RSVG ([source](https://github.com/HazAT/badge/blob/39fe92e4e4da1b5de2c156cfb164a7b8efd6bd2d/lib/badge/runner.rb#L131-L135)), see the additional message you get locally - so this is probably not related. Do you have additional output at the end on App Center you did not post? Stacktrace or something?

Comment: I currently think that this error message comes from the underlying software that is being used, probably `mini_magick` (or imagemagick which that uses). Hard to debug...

Comment: @janpio Hmm. Another observation I made is that this same lane (with `add_badge`) works as part of another project's build pipeline on App Center. I can't see anything that stands out between the two configurations other than both projects use different platforms; that should be irrelevant however since they both execute `add_badge` as part of `appcenter-pre-build.sh`.

Comment: "different platforms"?

Comment: @janpio This one is for a Xamarin solution, the other (working one) is for a React-Native project.

Comment: @janpio I wonder if perhaps the `yarn` that is executed in the RN project before the .sh script (mostly common to both projects) adds some dependency needed, thereby making it work.

Comment: You can try adding that, but as yarn is JS and fastlane and badge are both ruby, I don't see a connection there. For reference, this is the code that outputs the last successful line and where something probably goes wrong: https://github.com/HazAT/badge/blob/39fe92e4e4da1b5de2c156cfb164a7b8efd6bd2d/lib/badge/runner.rb#L106-L125 You could try creating an issue at that repo - maybe it rings a bell for the maintainer.

Comment: @janpio Awesome, thanks for that link. This is clearly an issue with no obvious fix, so if I manage to narrow it down to a culprit based on your suggestions, I’ll let you know and you can compile all your comments into an answer which I’d be happy to accept.

Comment: Awesome, let's hope you find a way to fix this for good.

Comment: @janpio Looking at that source file, I think the error may be here: `if @@rsvg_enabled
        new_path = "#{shield.path}.png"`. There’s not going to be a file with extension ‘.svg.png’, which seems consistent with the error in the output: “No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - 1558656638-staging-green.svg.png”.

Comment: As I understand it `shield.path` should be a `.svg` if `@@rsvg_enabled`. The code in line 113/115 then converts that to a `.svg.png`. This fails with `dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFont` error message which is the reason the file does not exist (and your second error message). Remember the `$ brew install librsvg` in your local output? Maybe doing that will let you replicate the error locally.

Comment: @janpio Yup you’re right. Could be that `rsvg-convert` is failing to produce the ‘.svg.png’ file. Anyway, I’ll try and install `librsvg` and replicate locally like you suggest.

Comment: was there any resolution to this? seeing this trying to add a badge to a Xamarin Android app on App Center. It works locally but not on App Center.